# Set width and height of Div using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 592px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.rt-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 592px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.placeholder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0 float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.child,
.subchild {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="placeholder">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="subchild">
        content should be placed here left bottom corner
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rt-content">
    <p>asdsadfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have to use flex 
The requirement is- width and height of placeholder should be based on content width and height + left padding....Need help in implementing this.
width is incresing but not height. need both height and width to fit according to content size.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here you can find how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Can you share a stylesheet where .placeholder, .child, and .subchild are defined?  Seeing what you've tried for styling may make it easier for someone to help you with a solution.

Comment: Please update the question with your best attempt and also link any resources and documentation you researched.